# Object does not match target type Exception in SetValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics, reflection

```
//try to set this property .

 public List<USER_ROLE> list {get;set;}

var result = new List<USER_ROLE>() { new USER_ROLE()
                              { userid = 0,role_id = 1,role_cde = "00001"
                               }};
    //Get property with name of property.

object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
var getva = property.GetValue(obj,null);// Object does not match target type


property.PropertyType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(obj,new object[] { result });
if (obj.GetType() == property.PropertyType)
{
property.SetValue(obj, property, null);// object does not match target type.
}
```

**Runtime execption: object does not match target type. i don't understand target type, please tell, where i am wrong?**

Comment: `PropertyType` is the return type of the property, while `obj` should be an instance of a class containing the property. You probably want to use `property.DeclaringType`

Comment: The fact that you're declaring a property and assigning values in the same scope seems a little bit bizarre.  Is this your literal code?

Comment: What you mean by bizarre man.? i am trying to make generic code for convert VM_propterties to Model properties.Are you have better solution ?

Comment: @FarhatUllah  by bizzare, I mean that the code that you posted won't actually compile

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1(v=vs.110).aspx), it seems as thought your first parameter is your original object, and you second parameter is the value that you want to set the property to.

It looks like you want to set the property to `obj`, in that case, you'd do

```
property.SetValue(/*instance of whatever class has the property*/, obj, null);
```